# Generating completely new vector based on other vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, interpolation, extrapolation

Assume I have four-vectors (v1,v2,v3,v4), and I want to create a new vector (vec_new) that is not close to any of those four-vectors. I was thinking about interpolation and extrapolation. Do you think they are suitable? Are they also apply for vector and generate a vector of let's say 300 dimensions? Another possible option would be the transformation matrix. But I am not sure if it fit my concern. I think averaging and concatenation are not the good ones as I might be close to some of those four-vectors. I am considering the cosine similarity as the measurement to find the closeness.

I got the vectors from the word2vec model. Based on some criteria, I split them into two categories. The splitting process is not important at all. The only important point is that there are some categories, and the vectors of that category are useful for that category. My concern is to add a new category that the vectors of this category have two conditions. First, the new category vectors are based on those two categories vectors. Second, new category vectors are as far as possible from those two categories vectors. There is no restriction for the procedure, but it should be valid and generalizable.

Any other ideas?

Comment: The four vectors are defined on $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: And how do you define "close"? Any restrictions on vec_new? Would a procedure like: "take the vector with the largest length, multiply by 10" work for you?

Comment: make a draw of v1, ..., v4 and the move to another country and make a new draw ofvec_new. It won't be close to the original vectors for sure. It can be proven that this works in any vector space of finite/infinite dimension (its important to leave the first draw at home.)

Comment: @user Yes they are in  ℝn space?

Comment: @Andrei, the closeness is based on cosine similarity score. And as for restriction, the suggested procedure doe not work.ction,

Comment: @sezarsampaio: You have to tell us why that procedure doesn't work, and tell us what procedures are allowed. Otherwise we're all just guessing, and your question will be closed as "needs more information".

Comment: because simply one can ask why to multiply by 10( for example). why not dividing by 10. based on my problem, I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a general case, if the given vectors span a subpace with dimension less than the dimension of the space, a possible way to create a new vector "not close" to the others is to take $v_5$ orthogonal to the span of the given vectors.

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking about orthogonality. good point

Comment: @sezarsampaio When we can proceed in that way, it is of course the best we can do!

Comment: What will happen if your if condition ("if the given vectors span a subpace with dimension less than the dimension of the space") does not satisfied? I edited the question.

Comment: @sezarsampaio I can't see at the moment a general approach to that. Suppose we are in $\mathbb R^3$ and $v_1=e_1$, $v_2=e_2$, $v_3=e_3$, $v_4=\frac{e_1+e_2+e_3}{\sqrt 3}$, what would be your best $v_5$ in this case, according ot your idea.

Comment: v5 could be a vector that is based on e1,e2,e3, e4 and is the negative of all as well.

Comment: @sezarsampaio In this sense maybe a definition as "opposite" could be better than orthogonal.